# Why are the OADs coming out for Days called the series finale when the manga isn't over?

Tags: days

I recently started reading *Days* manga and was curious about the anime. I began to watch it and got really into it so I wanted to know when the next season would come out.

I found out that they were not going to have a season 2 but instead three OADs, the websites I went on called it the series finale which confused me because the manga is still going on.

Why are the OADs coming out for *Days* called the series finale when the manga isn't over?

Answer (score 1):

**The 3 OADs will conclude the *Days anime series*, not the series as a whole.** Or in other words, there is no planned continuation for the anime after the OADs.

The anime series adapts the manga until the semifinal match of National Championship - Tokyo Preliminaries Block A. The last episode ends just before the start of the final match:

> The credits roll as both Touin and Seiseki take the field. There's a lot of high energy and everyone we've come to love throughout the series is watching the game. But we're not! Because the season has ended and we're left with a massive cliffhanger and one last 'Seiseki Fight!'
>
>  <sup>[DAYS Episode 24 (Final) Review: I Want to Play More Soccer With This Team](https://manga.tokyo/anime-review/days-episode-24-review/)</sup>

The planned 3 OADs will draw upon the final match of National Championship - Tokyo Preliminaries Block A, ending the arc and serving as **the anime's finale**.

Or just as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Days_(manga)#Anime) stated,

> the television anime's story will end with three original anime DVDs (OADs) in 2018.